# new Silverlight JetPack Business Application fails initialize STG_E_FILENOTFOUND

Tags: silverlight-4.0, themes, ria

I successfully built a Silverlight RIA services app on my previous laptop. Now I have a new laptop and am unable to start any project using the Silverlight Business Application (JetPack) template. It fails with a dialog:

![Microsoft Visual Studio
X could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030002
(STG_E_FILENOTFOUND))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GXVB.png)

and tries to display MainPage.xaml. The .web project is not created at all. There are 2 errors listed:

[image: Undefined CLR namespace]

I am running VS2010 Premium SP1 with NuGet 1.1 and downloaded the JetPack Business App template via NuGet. If I select the Silverlight Business Application template (the plain one, not the JetPack theme), it works perfectly, and creates both projects.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: One difference between my successful project and my current attempt is that I'm now running on a 64-bit chipset/Windows 7 OS. Previously it was 32-bit. But I don't expect this to be significant.

Comment: More clues: it is not a function of NuGet: I tried the original ZIP file that I used last time. That did not work either. Nor is it JetPack: the Windows7 themed RIA services template has the same error.